# Are 28 / 47 - 622 / 635 tubes ok to replace my 28 / 44 - 622 ones?

Tags: innertube

I recently got my first flat on my Cube hooper
It has 37 - 622 (28 x 1.40 - 700 x 35c) schwalbe tyres on it.

I ordered the new tube online before pulling the old one off, picking what I thought were the same tubes but the numbers are slightly different.

Are the 28 / 47 - 622 / 635 tubes i got ok to replace my 28 / 44 - 622 ones?

Thanks

Comment: The "28 / 47" is the range of tire widths the tube can accommodate.  37 is right in the middle, which is ideal.  Manufacturers tend to "stretch" the numbers a bit, and so you'd want to avoid, say, a 22/37 tube if the 28/47 is available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They would be perfectly fine. As their specification suggest (28 / 47 - 622 / 635 ) inner tubes can function in wide range of tyres.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They are in the specified range, they'll be fine.